# How do you install a package in the official backports repository using synaptic?

Tags: installation, synaptic, versions, backport

I would like to  install the current version of [hedgewars](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hedgewars) into Ubuntu using synaptic, but I'm not sure the exact steps.  I need to get my buddies playing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open synaptic and search for hedgewars.
You should see 2 packages.

select both packages, by using keyboard shortcut (shift click or control a)

From the package menu at the top, select "force version"

Select the newest hedgewars version from the menu box. click force version, 
Click apply button in synaptic.

Answer (score 1):

Go to **System Settings** > **Software & Updates**, select **Updates** tab and **Unsuported Updates**:

[image: Unsupported Updates]

Now go in [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal) and run the following command to update your repositories:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

After the update is complete, open **Synaptic** and search for "hedgewars" package:

[image: Synaptic]

Tick the packages that were found and install them

### Note:

Make sure that you comment Backports repositories in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, once done.  Reason: if you try to use synaptic to install gaim-encryption for example, you can find it in the backports repositories, but to install it, you would have to remove packages mozilla-firefox-gnome-support and ubuntu-desktop.

So go into `/etc/apt/sources.list` and comment out the backports repositories, and reload synaptic package manager.  There is an official version of gaim-encryption that did NOT conflict with the mozilla-firefox-gnome support and ubuntu-desktop packages.

<sup>Source:UF</sup>

Comment: thank you for the answer.  but I will probably accept the first answer that doesn't require editing a text file owned by root and using the command line

Comment: also, i just took 20 minutes to install a 13.04 from DVD into aVM, and backports was already clicked.